# Getting error "data corrupted" while parsing json in swift 4 for Mac OS Application

Tags: macos, swift4.1

I am getting an error in json parsing can anyone help me to solve the error.

My json data:

```
{
"message": "Batch found.",
"batch": {
    "batchID": "BA000000001",
    "name": "JUN-2014",
    "code": "TBATCH",
    "status": 1,
    "coordinatorName": null,
    "startDate": "2016-04-01T00:00:00",
    "endDate": "2020-04-01T00:00:00",
    "createdBy": "LU000000019",
    "createdOn": "2016-04-01T00:00:00",
    "updatedBy": "LU000000019",
    "updatedOn": "2018-10-11T11:51:46",
    "schoolID": "BS00001"
}
```

}

my code:
[image: Code Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **read** the error message and your code, the error is pretty clear:

It's just a typo: Dat**a** vs. Dat**e**

Both `startDate` and `endDate` are `Date`.

And you can delete the date formatter if you set the date decoding strategy to `.iso8601`

Comment: Ohhh, I never noticed